# Set checkbox checked or nonChecked if darkmode is activated | REACT

Tags: javascript, reactjs, tailwind-css, virtual-dom

Im new in react, i try the reference mode or state mode, but the page render a lot of times, or when i click in my checkbox, dont change the checked option.
Im using tailwind darkmode

when i load the page, there are a conditional that check if darkmode is activated or not,
so if loadind the page darkmode is enabled, the checkbox must be true and if not must be false, simply

```
import React, {useEffect, useState} from "react";

function Header() {
    const [darkMode, setDarkMode] = useState(false);
    useEffect(() =>{
        if (localStorage.theme === 'dark' || (!('theme' in localStorage) && window.matchMedia('(prefers-color-scheme: dark)').matches)) {
            document.documentElement.classList.add('dark')
            localStorage.theme = 'dark'
            setDarkMode(!darkMode)
          } else {
            document.documentElement.classList.remove('dark')
            localStorage.theme = 'light';
            console.log('modo luz activado')
          }
    },[])
    

  const changeTheme = () => {
    
    if (localStorage.theme === 'dark' || (!('theme' in localStorage) && window.matchMedia('(prefers-color-scheme: dark)').matches)) {
      document.documentElement.classList.remove("dark");
      localStorage.theme = "light";
    } else {
      document.documentElement.classList.add("dark");
      localStorage.theme = "dark";
    }
  };
  
  return (
    <header>
      <nav>
        <input checked={darkMode} type="checkbox" onChange={changeTheme} />
      </nav>
    </header>
  );
}

export default Header;
```

Comment: It looks like the culprit is your `if` condition in `changeTheme` function always resulting to `true`. Keep the condition short like so: `if (localStorage.theme === 'dark') { ... }`. Also, you are only using `setDarkMode` once. You'll need to use it everytime you change the value of localStorage.theme.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should have your `change theme` function like this:

```js
const changeTheme = () => {
    localStorage.theme = darkMode ? 'light' : 'dark'
    setDarkMode(!darkMode)
    if (darkMode) {
        document.documentElement.classList.remove("dark");
    } else {
        document.documentElement.classList.add("dark");
    }
};
```

Comment: This solution feels tacky. Firstly, you are changing the state of `darkMode` after you've just used it to set the value in localStorage. (weird!) Secondly, you are immediately using an `if-else` condition to further remove and add `classList` before ensuring that setDarkMode() has already finished its execution! (A big no-no) What do you think'll happen if I click the checkbox multiple times in a short span of time?

Comment: i know you are saying it right @RubekJoshi but these statements will not even take a millisecond to execute so don't worry about that

Answer (score 1):

You would normally use a `React.useContext()` for changing themes but since you are new here's how I would recommend you to approach this challenge:

```
import React, {useEffect, useState} from "react";

function Header() {
    const [darkMode, setDarkMode] = useState( // initialize your state here directly
      localStorage.theme === 'dark' ||
      (!('theme' in localStorage) && window.matchMedia('(prefers-color-scheme: dark)').matches)
    );
    
    useEffect(() => { // move your logic part here
      if (!darkMode) {
        document.documentElement.classList.add('dark')
        localStorage.theme = 'dark'
      } else {
        document.documentElement.classList.remove('dark')
        localStorage.theme = 'light';
      }
    }, [darkMode])
    

  const changeTheme = () => {
    setDarkMode(!darkMode) // now just worry about changing your state
  };
  
  return (
    <header>
      <nav>
        <input checked={darkMode} type="checkbox" onChange={changeTheme} />
      </nav>
    </header>
  );
}

export default Header;
```

The benefit of doing it this way is that you are handling your theme logic reactively. You are watching for change in your state and implementing your logic instead of implementing your logic each time **and** changing your state each time as well.

Comment: challenge accepte